# Embed web browser as component in React app

Tags: reactjs, browser, electron, nwjs

I'm looking for a way to embed a browser in a React application with the ability to add onclick events on search page selectors. I'm wondering if I could use Electron or NW.js.  Does anybody have an idea?

I started with iframes at first, but here's the problem with cross domain.  Then I thought about puppeteer and png rendering with positioning, but it's not very intuitive.  And recently I found threads about Electron and NW.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what you mean by "embed a browser in a React app". A browser is an executable that renders HTML/CSS/JS. React is a JS library that runs *in* a browser.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe embed a different *website* on the same page? In which case, yes you would use an iframe. There are many security contraints put in place, for good reason.

Electron is a Node.js script that spawns a chromium browser that can communicate with a separate Node process.

NW.js is a modified Chromium browser with Node.js built in.

Both of them are going to have security restrictions similar to a normal browser. NW.js has some additional options you could try (again, not sure what you actually want). But there are still server-side restrictions for CORS that you'd need to deal with no matter what.

I think the real solution here is for you to re-evaluate what your *goal* is, and then find a better solution to it.

More on NW.js/Electron at:

- https://xpda.net

Comment: How can `NW.js` claim "It lets you call Node.js code and modules directly from browser"? Browsers are sandboxed: you can't use NodeJS' standard library functions to open raw sockets or access the filesytem inside a browser... UPDATE: Ah, [it seems to use PNaCl](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Use%20NaCl%20in%20NW.js/) - but PNaCl is obsolete and replaced with WASM - and WASM is still sandboxed, so low-level IO should still be impossible...

Comment: NW.js is a run time environment executable used for making desktop apps. It is a modified Chromium browser with Node.js built in. You can do anything Chromium or Node can do with it, and directly from the DOM.

Comment: He wants to run a browser inside a web page so he can log user interactions. For instance, given a list of google search results, he wants to measure the spent time in each clicked page. Iframe has restrictions.